# Naming elements of a list with `with` statement

Tags: python, list, sequence, with-statement

I want to refer to an element (`mem[0]`) of a list (`mem`) with a different name (`fetch`):

```
mem = [0]
f = open("File.lx", "rb").read()
for b in f: mem += [b]
size = len(mem)

while mem[0] < size:        #using mem[0]
    char = (mem[0]*2)+1
    source = mem[char]
    target = mem[char + 1]

    mem[0] += 1
    mem[target] = mem[source]
```

And I tried that with the `with` statement:

```
mem = [0]
f = open("File.lx", "rb").read()
for b in f: mem += [b]
size = len(mem)

with mem[0] as fetch:        #with statement
   while fetch < size:       #using mem[0] as fetch
    char = (fetch*2)+1
    source = mem[char]
    target = mem[char + 1]

    fetch += 1
    mem[target] = mem[source]
```

But I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\documents\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    with mem[0] as fetch:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I thought this would be the way because that's how it's done with file objects:

```
with open("File.lx", "rb") as file:
    fileBytes = file.read()
```

I read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with-stmt) for the `with` statement and it says that the `__exit()__` and `__enter()__` methods are loaded. According to what I understood after reading that and from the `AttributeError`, my guess is that sequence elements (`mem[0]`) do not have an `__enter()__` method.

Comment: The item at `mem[0]` is a literal (in this case, an integer, `0`). A literal doesn't have the `__enter()__` method

Comment: Maybe try to explain why you think you need to do this. There is almost certainly a much simpler way to achieve it

Comment: and you need to read the next [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#)

Comment: Why not simply `fetch = mem[0]` without the `with`? There isn't any clean-up for `with` to do. Garbage collection will take care of any memory used.

Comment: @JohnColeman In some instances the last line (`mem[target] = mem[source]`) will refer to `mem[0]` and the value of `fetch` has to update as well.

Comment: But with `with` used with a file, the file handle doesn't "update" in the body of the `with` Ints are immutable and `fetch` would be an int.

Answer (score 2):

as the comments already mentioned, `mem[0]` is a literal integer, which doesn't have `__enter__` and `__exit__` which are required for the `as` keyword to work and it would be indeed simpler if you just used `mem[0]`

but that would be too easy, what you CAN do (as an exercise don't actually do this)
is extend the `int` class and add `__enter__` and `__exit__` like so:

```
class FancyInt(int):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

mem = [FancyInt(0)]
with mem[0] as fetch:
    print(fetch)
```

this is neat but `fetch` is an alias to a **LITERAL!** if you change `fetch`, `mem[0]` will not change!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a mutable object which functions as an alias for a specific location in a list. I could see *some* utility in that (since explicit indices are somewhat ugly in Python). You could create such a class. Here is a proof of concept, implementing the three things that you tried to do with `fetch` in your code:

```
class Fetcher:
    def __init__(self,target_list, index):
        self._list = target_list
        self._i = index

    def __iadd__(self,v):
        self._list[self._i] += v
        return self

    def __mul__(self,v):
        return self._list[self._i] * v

    def __lt__(self,v):
        return self._list[self._i] < v
```

For example,

```
mem = [0,1,2]
fetch = Fetcher(mem,0)

print(fetch < 2) #true
mem[0] = 1
print(fetch < 2) #still true
fetch += 1
print(fetch < 2) #false!
print(mem[0]) #2, showing that mem[0] was changed
print(fetch*2) #4 -- but 2*fetch won't work!
```

The last line shows that there is a limit to what you could achieve here. To make this really useful, you would want to implement many more magic methods (beyond `__iadd__` etc.). Whether or not all this is useful just to avoid `[0]`, you be the judge.